# OpenTracing Python requests: Propagate span

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, opentracing, jaeger

I have a Python `Flask` application that uses the `requests` library. I am trying to implement OpenTracing in the application. A simplified version is:

```
from flask_opentracing import FlaskTracer
from flask import Flask
from jaeger_client import Config
from opentracing_instrumentation.client_hooks import install_all_patches
from os import getenv
import requests

JAEGER_HOST = getenv('JAEGER_HOST', 'localhost')


def initialise_tracer():
    config = Config(
        config={
            'local_agent': {
                'reporting_host': 'jaeger'
            }
        },
        service_name='opentracing_test',
        validate=True
    )
    return config.initialize_tracer()


app = Flask(__name__)
tracer = FlaskTracer(initialise_tracer, trace_all_requests=True, app=app)
install_all_patches()


@app.route('/foo')
def foo():
    r = requests.get('http://localhost/bar')
    return 'foo : ' + r.text


@app.route('/bar')
def bar():
    return 'bar'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

All endpoints are traced because of giving `trace_all_requests` to `FlaskTracer`. All requests made with the `requests` library are traced because of `install_all_patches()` from `opentracing_instrumentation`.

My `'/foo'` endpoint makes a request to `'/bar'`. When I access the `'/foo'` endpoint and view the traces, I can see two separate traces: One containing just `'/foo'`, and a second that contains both the `requests` GET and the call to `'/bar'`. I would have expected the spans to propagate through the entire process and therefore I should see a single trace with `'/foo'` -> `GET` -> `'/bar'`.

Do I need to manually set the headers on each of my `requests` to pass the span? It looks like that is exactly what the `requests` monkey patch should do...

Comment: Please answer yourself if you solved it!